# Is there any existing engine which can be converted to turbofan from turboshaft in mid flight?

Tags: jet-engine, rotorcraft, cruise, hover

I read about convertible engines. I want to know if there is any engine existing to meet up hover and cruise together.

Answer (score 4):

The closest one is the [P&W F-135](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratt_%26_Whitney_F135), used in the F-35B VTOL-capable fighter. However, it switches between turbofan and turbofan+turboshaft modes. The fan's still running, but its flow is redirected down through thrust vectoring for hovering.

Here it is shown driving a lift fan, which includes the gearbox.
A similar but larger gearbox can be used to drive a helicopter rotor, if necessary.

This particular engine is too large for a practical-sized helicopter. But it might be possible to convert smaller engines in a similar way.

[image]
[image]

Comment: To be precise, the F-135 is capable of switching between turbofan and turbofan/turboshaft hybrid mode. It never operates in turboshaft only -mode.

Comment: You could also state that it is a turbofan engine, period. One with a large power off-take in STOVL configuration. Even in STOVL mode the exhaust needs to provide a relative large airflow.

Comment: Is there any internal modification of turbofan engine other than connecting the drive shaft required to use a turbofan engine both in hover and cruise condition like F-35B's engine ?

Comment: @NahidaIslam For optimum performance or FADEC, perhaps. But generally almost any turbofan should be able to drive a gearbox instead of the fan or in addition to it.

Comment: In this case how to find the shaft power if turbofan is used?

Comment: @NahidaIslam That's too big a question for comments. And you'd need to pick a specific engine or specific power range to get a good answer. It's a very wide variation.

Comment: How to calculate shaft power for GE CF34 engine?

Comment: @NahidaIslam You should ask a separate question for that. Specify what you need to know and why, if possible.